# When did the term "liberal democracy" first appear?

Tags: political-history, democracy, ideology

Reading through Western political history (whether Europe or North and South America) prior to the late 20th century, I see many references to "republicanism" and to "democracy".  Getting into the 19th century I start to see terms like "radicals", "democrats", "socialists" and "liberals".  Towards the end of the century, the term "social democracy" starts to appear (basically meaning Marxism).  But I haven't found any references to "liberal democracy".  In contemporary discourse on the other hand, "liberal democracy" seems to be the only democracy in town (though recently people mention something called "illiberal democracy", which is supposedly very bad, or at least not as good).

I'm fairly clear on what people mean by "liberal democracy", but I'd like to know who coined this term exactly, when it first appeared and when it came into widespread usage.  Seems like a mid-20th century term, probably arising from the cold war, but I haven't been able to find any confirmation of this anywhere.

Comment: Welcome to History:Stack Exchange. Thank you for your question; please consider revising it to be more in line with our community expectations. Like many other stacks, we expect questions to [provide evidence of prior research](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3227/1599). That helps us to understand the question, and avoids our repeating work you've already done. Our [help], and [other stacks](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3224/how-do-i-write-a-good-question) provide additional resources to assist with revisions.

Comment: This may be too generic of a term to find an individual source. Searching books limited to the 19th century I find plenty of hits, so its not a new phrase.

Comment: The OED has [this from John Adams](https://books.google.com/books?id=I31bAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA18#v=onepage&q&f=false) in 1787